# Php script to continue if mysql fails

Tags: php, mysql, xml, get

I have this code for an app i'm working on:

```
    <?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
//Gather data and prepare query
$thequery = urlencode($_GET['s']);
$yhost = 'http://boss.yahooapis.com';
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$url = $yhost.'/ysearch/news/v1/'.$thequery.'?appid='.$apikey.'&format=xml';
//Get the results
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = str_replace( array('<abstract>', '</abstract>'), array('<description>', '</description>'), $data);
$results = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
//echo the results
echo $results->asXML();
?>
```

Where i have this line: `$thequery = urlencode($_GET['s']);` i'd like to log this to a DB but its obviously very important that the XML gets outputted so how can i make sure, if the mysql bit fails for whatever reason, the XML still gets outputted? Or am i overcomplicating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to ensure NO output return to browser/client when you performing database manipulation

Answer (score 1):

That's easy to solve, just prepend your mysql commands with an @ (or set error display to off) and check the return codes:

```
$ret = @mysql_query($query);
if(!$ret) {
    do error handling;
} else {
    continue with something else;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this...with this though, the mysql errors are going to be dealt with, its much more important that the xml gets outputted rather than the mysql error being solved...

Comment: where's the problem? just do `if($ret != false) {output your mysql things}`, and the if clause will simply not get executed if there was a Mysql error.