# PHP safely logging to mysql but continuing script if fail

Tags: php, mysql, xml, api

Hey, i've just made an iphone app and i'm getting the user to enter a search term. I'm then taking that search term and sending it up to a PHP page on my webhost, i'm then querying some RSS feeds and returning xml back down to the app. What i'm interesting in doing is logging the users search term into a DB and then returning the XML as normal. Whats obviously more important is that the user gets the xml rather than the term being logged. So what could i add to the below code to make sure the XML is safely returned regardless of whether the mysql fails?

Any ideas?

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
//Gather data and prepare query
$thequery = urlencode($_GET['s']);
$yhost = 'http://boss.yahooapis.com';
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$url = $yhost.'/ysearch/news/v1/'.$thequery.'?appid='.$apikey.'&format=xml';
//Get the results
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$results = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
//echo the results
echo $results->asXML();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine using standard DB syntax, eg:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if ($link) {
   // do your DB operations
   mysql_close($link);
}

// output your XML
```

What this will do is attempt to connect to your DB and run your insert (logging) query. Regardless of failure, the XML will then be output.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a repeated question I had answered before,

try

```
ob_start();
  /* code for database insertion */
ob_end_flush(); // ob_end_clean, ob_get_contents...
```

details on output buffering : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

However, for logging user search, do a parse on apache log is much easier (GET only),
and benefits for better page optimization in term of less resources used

**updated** ... same question from you ... [Php script to continue if mysql fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244796/php-script-to-continue-if-mysql-fails/)

Comment: @benhowdle89 - no worry, if the logging is not mission critical, i suggest use a cron to parse the daily apache log and update into database

Comment: yeah might be better actually! Can i access those logs if i'm with a web host!? Will they let me see that...

Comment: @benhowdle89 - that i cannot answer you. better to check with your hosting company, **THEY SHOULD** provide but maybe some charges applied too

Comment: Well it will be worth it if i find out whether people like Lady Gaga more than Justin Bieber ;) NOT.

Comment: @benhowdle89 - lady gaga ... cause she has the biggest facebook fans